# How to find y in this problem?

Tags: functions

So here is the problem

$$x=\dfrac{1}{4y^2} - \dfrac{1}{2\ln y}$$

It is not so hard I know but lny is my enemy here. I gave e for all of them as a base but it became even more complicated

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax to format your math expressions. In this case, is the equation $x=\frac{1}{4y^2}-\frac{1}{2\ln(y)}$ or $x=\frac14y^2-\frac12\ln(y)$?

Comment: If you mean the equation $x=\frac14y^2-\frac12\ln(y)$ and want to solve for $y$: with "elementary" functions, that's not hard. It's impossible.  With Lambert's W-function, it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $x = \frac{y^2}{4} - \frac{\ln(y)}{2}$, the solutions of that are
$$ y = \sqrt{- W\left(-e^{-4x}\right)}$$ where $W$ is a branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
Assuming you only want real solutions, you need $x \ge 1/4$, and either the $0$ or $-1$ branch of $W$ can be used.

If you don't want to use Lambert W, you could use numerical methods to approximate a solution: there is no exact solution using elementary functions.